# On the classic example of the sequence $f_n=x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences

I asked a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3546841/example-of-a-sequence-of-f-n-converging-to-f-pointwise-but-not-uniformly-and) but didn't get a full explanation, so I would like to ask a simpler related question.

The sequence of continuous functions
\begin{equation*}
f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^n,\quad x\in[0,1)\\
1,\quad x=1
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
converges pointwise to
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0,\quad x\in[0,1)\\
1,\quad x=1
\end{cases},
\end{equation*}
which is not continuous.

In particular, we know that uniform convergence is needed to guarantee that the limit is continuous. But this is a sequence of continuous functions on $[0,1]$, shouldn't its limit be continuous?

Comment: No, that's precisely what this example illustrates. If the convergence is uniform, the limit is continuous. If it's not, the limit doesn't have to be continuous.

Comment: @Wojowu Sure. But then this is not a counterexample of $C([a,b])$ being complete because $f_n$ is only Cauchy in $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ while not in $(C([a,b]),||\cdot||_{C([a,b])})$?

Comment: For the functions $f_n$, why distinguish the cases $x \neq 1$ and  $x = 1$? It is automatically true that $1^n = 1$.

Comment: @Edu The convergence in $C([a,b])$ **is** the uniform convergence, as the metric is given by $d(f,g)=max_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)-g(x)|$, so if $d(f,g)<\varepsilon$, it means that $|f(x)-g(x)|<\varepsilon$ *for all* $x\in[a,b]$ - i.e. *independently* of $x$. By the way, the sequence you've presented is neither Cauchy nor convergent in $C([0,1])$.

Comment: You are answering yourself: " we know that uniform convergence is needed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user *5xum* says in their answer, no: the limit of a sequence of continuous functions in not required to be continuous.  In this case you can get a feel for what's happening geometrically by drawing the graph of $$f_n = x^n$$ on the interval $[0,1]$ for several values of $n$; say $n=1,10,100$ and $1000$.  You'll see that the curve flattens towards the start of the interval, getting closer to the $x$-axis, and steepens towards the end of the interval, becoming closer and closer to vertical.  It's as though in the limit the curve finally reaches $90^\circ$ and snaps, so that the last point separates from an otherwise flat curve.

Generalising this a little leads to the notion of *[Baire classes](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Baire_classes)* of functions. Continuous functions form *Baire class 0*, and the limits of continuous functions form *Baire class 1*, and we can build them up into a hierarchy.  (Which turns out not to contain all possible functions either, so there exists non-Baire-class functions though they're a little tricky to conceptualise.)  An interesting fact is that the derivative of a differentiable function is a Baire class one [function](https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/huh.pdf).

Answer (score 7):

> shouldn't its limit be continuous?

No, because the convergence is not uniform.